# Which good version combination of RelStorage for Plone 5.x

Tags: plone, relstorage

I tried to install Plone5.1RC1 / RelStorage2.x / psycopg2.7x, but I got an error. then I tried to install Plone5.0x / RelStorage1.6x-2.x / psycopg2.7x, but I got an error.

Please let me know, best version combination of RelStorage for Plone 5.0.x and Plone 5.1.

Comment: Hi Manabu! I posted a link to your question on our forum: https://community.plone.org/t/which-good-version-combination-of-relstorage-for-plone-5-x/5249 – probably you will get more people seeing your question if you post there.

Comment: There was a similar thread here: https://community.plone.org/t/cannot-get-relstorage-2-with-plone-5-to-work-importerror-cannot-import-name-resolvedserial/4458/3 but things could have changed since then (July).

Comment: It would be very helpful for the error message you got to be pasted into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Plone 5.0:   Relstorage 1.6.3

For Plone 5.1:   Relstorage 2.0

However, be sure to have your Python version up to date. (>=2.7.9)  or you'll have an issue with Plone 5.1 requiring ZEO 5.1.1 and Relstorage requiring ZEO < 5.0

Source: https://github.com/zodb/relstorage/blob/5ab2840552066d0cca4db85ac8b51041ef778357/setup.py#L127

Comment: disclamer: I have not successfully built 5.1-pending with relstorage.